# Continue to calculate with the outcome

Tags: c#

I am creating a calculator in c#. Something's not working for me. A standard calculation works for me. For example `13+15`. The result is then `28`. But if I want to continue calculating with `28`, it goes wrong. For example `28 (the result of the previous sum) + 3`. You would say it is `31`, but my calculator comes out at `21`. This is with every math problem, if I want to calculate further with it. How can I make sure it's correct? Do I need a loop? I do want to be able to continue calculating with the result `31`. Does anyone have an idea how I can take care of this?
Btw: I have asked this question earlier, but the answers were all wrong:(.

This is my code (feel free to put it in there ;))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string first = "";
        string second = "";
        string userInput = "";
        string space = " ";
        char function;
        int times;
        double result;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void number1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "1";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }
        private void number2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "2";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "3";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "4";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "5";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "6";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "7";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "8";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "9";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            first = "";
            second = "";
            userInput = "";
            result = 0.0;
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "0";
            feedback.Text = "";
            times = 0;
        }

        private void divideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '/';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "÷";     
        }

        private void multiplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '*';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "*";
        }

        private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '+';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "+";
        }

        private void minusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '-';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "-";
        }

        private void equalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            times++;
            second = userInput;
            double firstNum, secondNum;
            firstNum = Convert.ToDouble(first);
            secondNum = Convert.ToDouble(second);
            
            if (function =='+')
            {
                result = firstNum + (secondNum * times);
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = (result - secondNum) + space + "+" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
            else if(function == '-')
            {
                result = firstNum - (secondNum * times);
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = (result+secondNum) + space + "-" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
            else if (function == '/')
            {
                if(secondNum == 0)
                {
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = "Error";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = firstNum / Math.Pow(secondNum, times);
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                    feedback.Text = result*secondNum + space + "÷" + space + second + space + "=";
                }
            }
            else if (function == '*')
            {
                result = firstNum * Math.Pow(secondNum, times);
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = result/secondNum + space + "*" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
        }
        
        private void decimalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text += ".";
        }

        private void zeroButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "0";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger? It seems like this is more of a debugging problem than anything else. The first thing I would do is look at the values of `first` and `second` before you convert them to `double` in `equalButton_Click` to make sure you even have the right values in the first place. The second thing I noticed is that `secondNum * times` looks suspiciously illogical. `15 + (3 * 2)` -> `21`. If `firstNum` is `15` rather than `28` and `times` is `2` when you do the second calculation, that wuld give you `21`.

Comment: Okay, I will step through it in debugger. I understand the second thing you noticed but i don't know how can i make sure that when i click the equalbutton, i can make sure that the second number continues to be added. For example if I do 3+5=8. If I then click on the equalButton, it should become 8+5=13. 13+5=18, etc.

Comment: Update: I have put it in debugger, but I don't have feedback or anything like that from it.

Comment: Don't think of it as "second number continues to be added". You're getting ahead of yourself. Just make sure that the variables have the right values at every point in time. That's why debugging and examining variables in the Watch window is so important. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try it, but I am pretty new to programming and especially c#;)

Comment: This is the ***absolute best time*** to learn how to use the debugger and develop your debugging skills, at the very start of your learning. Too many people delay that step and cannot progress beyond the beginner stage. Without the debugger and good debugging skills, you can expect persistent failure and frustration.

Answer (score 1):

As has been commented on the original post, learning to use the debugger is key here.

---

Following the state of `first`, `second` and `userInput`, this is what I see (manual debugging for the sake of trying to guide you a little bit):

After having performed the first calculation (`13 + 15 =`), this is what you will have:

> first = "13"
> second = "15"
> userInput = "15"

(None of these values are reset at the end of `equalButton_Click()`, which may be expected?)

Then, you click the `+` button, and your state is updated to:

> **first = "15"** // userInput value
> second = "15"
> **userInput = ""** // reset

Then, you click the `3` button, and your state is updated to:

> first = "15"
> second = "15"
> **userInput = "3"**

Then, you click the `=` button, which updates the state to:

> first = "15"
> **second = "3"**
> userInput = "3"

Seeing as you are using your `times` counter, which is now equal to 2 (after having clicked the `=` button twice in total), your calculation will therefore be `15 + (3 * 2)` => `15 + 6` => `21`.

Comment: As a sidenote, I agree with user madreflection about the `times` counter -- I do believe it will do more harm than good.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you say. The only problem is that I don't know what I must change (a lot, I think) in my code. If you know how my code must be, I would appreciate it if you can tell me how.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be "a lot". Unfortunately, you've acquired a bit of technical debt in your design and that's presenting more challenges than you can address with a few small changes. We can't tell you what it "should" be because that's your decision to make. You need to learn by doing. The best thing to do right now is start a new project and try doing things differently, avoiding what you know to be mistakes (and hopefully, you do know what those mistakes are). As you learn to write granular and loosely coupled components, there's less work to do when you start over.

Comment: @HenkAap: Take note... this is a good example of how you should be testing your code. Execute a statement, examine the changes. It's far easier to know what you did wrong if you look at it this way. It may take a few (or many) times before you see the mistake, but at least you have an opportunity to see it.

Comment: @AstridE.: Good explanation of how the values change at each step.